# combine php array, with matching values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a set of php arrays

```
$arrayOne = (
    0 => new,
    1 => old,
    2 => fresh,
    3 => new,
    4 => old,
    5 => fresh,
    6 => new,
    7 => old,
    8 => fresh,

    )
$arrayTwo = (
   0 => yellow,
   1 => green,
   2 => red,
   3 => blue,
   4 => grey,
   5 => orange,
   6 => purple,
   7=> pink,
   8 => brown
   )
$arrayThree = (
  0 => Monday
  1 => Tuesday
  2 => Wednesday
  3 => Thursday
  4 => Friday
  5 => Saturday
  6 => Sunday
  7 => Monday2
  8 => Monday3
  )
```

These array's are being looped though and placed in a table

```
for($index = 0; index < 100; $index++){

 $returnVariable .= '<td>'.$ArrayOne[$index].'</td>';
 $returnVariable .= '<td>'.$ArrayTwo[$index].'</td>';
 $returnVariable .= '<td>'.$ArrayThree[$index].'</td>';
```

}

When returned and displayed on the page the table works just as intended with everything matched how they are supposed to be

```
new    yellow    monday
old    green     tuesday
fresh  red       wednesday
```

etc,etc, I would like to group the first column so that it list all the 'new', then all the 'old', then all the fresh, while keeping the intended matching ex,

```
new   yellow     monday
new   blue       thursday
new   purple     sunday
old   green      tuesday
old   grey       friday
old   pink       Monday2
```

etc etc

Comment: How did these related sets of data end up in separate arrays to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, join the three arrays into one. Then, sort the new array by the first value (new first, then old, then fresh):

```
<?php    
$arrayOne = [
    0 => "new",
    1 => "old",
    2 => "fresh",
    3 => "new",
    4 => "old",
    5 => "fresh",
    6 => "new",
    7 => "old",
    8 => "fresh",

];
$arrayTwo = [
   0 => "yellow",
   1 => "green",
   2 => "red",
   3 => "blue",
   4 => "grey",
   5 => "orange",
   6 => "purple",
   7=> "pink",
   8 => "brow"
];
$arrayThree = [
  0 => "Monday",
  1 => "Tuesday",
  2 => "Wednesday",
  3 => "Thursday",
  4 => "Friday",
  5 => "Saturday",
  6 => "Sunday",
  7 => "Monday2",
  8 => "Monday3",
];
echo "<pre>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayOne); $i++) {
    $array[] = [
        $arrayOne[$i],
        $arrayTwo[$i],
        $arrayThree[$i],
    ];
}
$values = [ // give these strings a numeric value to compare them
    "new" => 0,
    "old" => 1,
    "fresh" => 2,
];
usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($values) {
    return $values[$a[0]] - $values[$b[0]];
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/RIlWg)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Create new array to hold all then sort it and implode it into a string 
   <?php
    $arrayOne = array(
        0 => "new",
        1 => "old",
        2 => "fresh",
        3 => "new",
        4 => "old",
        5 => "fresh",
        6 => "new",
        7 => "old",
        8 => "fresh",

        );
    $arrayTwo = array(
       0 => "yellow",
       1 => "green",
       2 => "red",
       3 => "blue",
       4 => "grey",
       5 => "orange",
       6 => "purple",
       7=> "pink",
       8 => "brown"
       );
    $arrayThree =array(
      0 => "Monday",
      1 => "Tuesday",
      2 => "Wednesday",
      3 => "Thursday",
      4 => "Friday",
      5 => "Saturday",
      6 => "Sunday",
      7 => "Monday2",
      8 => "Monday3"
      );
    $returnVariable=array();
    for($index = 0; $index<count($arrayOne); $index++){

     $returnVariable[$index][0]= '<td>'.$arrayOne[$index].'</td>';
     $returnVariable[$index][1]= '<td>'.$arrayTwo[$index].'</td>';
     $returnVariable[$index][2]= '<td>'.$arrayThree[$index].'</td>';

    }
    sort($returnVariable);
    echo "<table>";
     for ($i=0; $i<count($returnVariable); $i++) {
            if (@is_array($returnVariable[$i])) 
                $returnVariable[$i] = implode($returnVariable[$i]," ");
    echo "<tr>";

        print $returnVariable[$i];
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight-forward solution:

```
$arrayOne = array(0 => "new",1 => "old",2 => "fresh",3 => "new",4 => "old",5 => "fresh",6 => "new",7 => "old",8 => "fresh",);
$arrayTwo = array(0 => "yellow",1 => "green",2 => "red",3 => "blue",4 => "grey",5 => "orange",6 => "purple",7=> "pink",8 => "brown");
$arrayThree = array(0 => "Monday",1 => "Tuesday",2 => "Wednesday",3 => "Thursday",4 => "Friday",5 => "Saturday",6 => "Sunday",7 => "Monday2",8 => "Monday3");

$result = [];
foreach($arrayOne as $k => $v){
    $result[$v][] = "<tr><td>$v</td><td>{$arrayTwo[$k]}</td><td>{$arrayThree[$k]}</td></tr>";
}

echo '<table>';
foreach(['new', 'old', 'fresh'] as $k){
    echo implode("", $result[$k]);
}
echo '</table>';
```

The output (push "*Run code snippet*"):

```html
<table border="1"><tr><td>new</td><td>yellow</td><td>Monday</td></tr><tr><td>new</td><td>blue</td><td>Thursday</td></tr><tr><td>new</td><td>purple</td><td>Sunday</td></tr><tr><td>old</td><td>green</td><td>Tuesday</td></tr><tr><td>old</td><td>grey</td><td>Friday</td></tr><tr><td>old</td><td>pink</td><td>Monday2</td></tr><tr><td>fresh</td><td>red</td><td>Wednesday</td></tr><tr><td>fresh</td><td>orange</td><td>Saturday</td></tr><tr><td>fresh</td><td>brown</td><td>Monday3</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is

```
 $row ="";
 $temp = array();
 foreach($arrayOne as $key => $value){
  $temp[$value][] = $key;
 }
foreach($temp as $value){
   foreach($value as $value2){
     $row .= ' '.$arrayOne[$value2].'';
     $row .= ' '.$arrayTwo[$value2].'';
     $row .= ' '.$arrayThree[$value2]."\n";
   }
}
echo $row;
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/850007